# Varying Multidimentional Postgresql column

Tags: python, postgresql

I keep getting the following error: 'multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions'. The data that is inserted into the column varies in dimensions, so it is impossible to match the expressions with the dimensions.  For example, the column could have the following input.  I am using Python and inserting the data into PostgreSQL.

How would write the script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "participants" (
    "id"        BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    "participants"      VARCHAR ARRAY);

script = 'INSERT INTO participants (id, participants) VALUES (%s, %s)'

record = [1, [['Tom'], ['Steve', 'Ron'], ['Cheryl', 'Rick', 'Sue']]
record = [2, [['Jane', 'Frank, 'Lin']]
record = [3, [['Jose', 'Rhonda'], ['Stephanie', 'Joe']]
record = [4, [['Pedro', 'Sandra']]
```

The outcome should be as follows:

```
| id       |                        participants                     |
| -------- | ------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1        | {{'Tom'}, {'Steve', 'Ron'}, {'Cheryl', 'Rick', 'Sue'}}  |
| 2        | {{'Jane', 'Frank, 'Lin'}}                               |
| 3        | {{'Jose', 'Rhonda'}, {'Stephanie', 'Joe'}}              |
| 4        | {{'Pedro', 'Sandra'}}                                   |
```

Comment: I think your case suits for jsonb data type which means no more strictly defined arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participants (
    id        BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    participants      json);

insert into participants values
(1, '[["Tom"], ["Steve", "Ron"], ["Cheryl", "Rick", "Sue"]]'::json),
(2, '[["Jane", "Frank", "Lin"]]'::json),
(3, '[["Jose", "Rhonda"], ["Stephanie", "Joe"]]'::json),
(4, '[["Pedro", "Sandra"]]'::json);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eftbJnWp)

As Sahap said json or jsonb can be used not to hit dimension constraint. Yet, doing so you will not be able to use some useful functions such as [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-array.html#:%7E:text=%E2%86%92%20%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D-,unnest,-(%20anyarray%20)%20%E2%86%92). There are great contents if you want to convert it to array for practical use. You can start with [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array). However, you might still need to customize them.